# Apparently wrong section index title after NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am currently facing a (to me) strange issue as follows:

I have a child MOC (`NSManagedObjectContext`) with about two dozen MOs (`NSManagedObject`s). Each MO has an optional Boolean attribute `flag`. All of these are set to `@(NO)`. `fetchedResultsController` is an `NSFetchedResultsController` which fetches these MOs, whose `managedObjectContext` is `moc` and whose `sectionNameKeyPath` is `@"flag"`. `fetchedResultsController` also has an [sort descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620460/1789384) on `flag` (and another secondary sort attribute).

After running these lines of code

```
NSAssert(!moc.hasChanges, nil); // no unsaved changes
BOOL flag = [fetchedResultsController performFetch: &error];
NSAssert(flag && (error == nil), nil); // no errors
```

I observe the following:

1. `fetchedResultsController.fetchedResults` contains as many MOs as does `moc` and all their flags are `@(NO)` (as one would expect).
2. `fetchedResultsController.sections.count` and `fetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles.count` are both `1` (as one would expect, since all `flag`s have the same value).
3. `fetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles[0]` is `@"1"`.

The third item appears wrong to me. I would have expected `@"0"` (since this is the [capitalized first letter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/sectionIndexTitleForSectionName:) of `[@(NO) description]`).

What could be wrong here and how can I obtain the right section index title in this case?

**UPDATE** I now looks as if the problem may be ([still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465031/order-of-sections-produced-by-nsfetchedresultscontroller)) related to employing `flag` (an optional Boolean Core Data attribute) as `sectionNameKeyPath`. Even if values of `flag` differ, `performFetch:` leads to only one section titled `@"1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not reliable to rely on the `description` implementation of the section title field. This might be appropriate for a string but it seems counter-intuitive that this is the intended solution for numeric values. You probably do not want these values in your final implementation anyway.

You should implement `sectionIndexTitleForSectionName`, check the boolean value there and return a proper string. Note that this method already receives a string, so you need to check if it is the right one. I suspect it is not, and you have to make sure that the NSNumber generates the correct string. Maybe you need to add a method to `NSNumber` as a category to return the proper string for the boolean value. Your `sectionNameKeyPath` would then be something like "flag.toString" or similar.

Another thing you might want to check: depending on how you set up your managed object subclasses and your model, you might have forgotten to de-reference the value of the `NSNumber`.

```
BOOL falseValue = @(NO).boolValue; // NO
```

but

```
BOOL falseValue = @(NO);           // YES
```

Comment: I think you got it almost right: implementing `sectionIndexTitleForSectionName` does not help, because it receives already a derived `NSString`, no longer the Boolean. I was indeed mistaken in assuming that the derivation was done with `description`. What solves the problem is defining a category on `NSString` with a method say, `toString` for deriving `NSString`s from `NSNumber`s , and control the derivation with `sectionNameKeyPath`set to  `flag.toString`. Do you want to update you answer accordingly? If so, I shall accept, because the current version put me on the right track.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. It seems to me that you need a category on `NSNumber`, though, rather than on `NSString`.

Comment: Yep, `NSNumber` (typo).